# How to avoid ajax result on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[image: screen1]

As you in sample above I have placeholder (option without value) to say eg. `Select Subcategory` but as soon as I change my category value result of subcategories will show.

What I want is when I select category in subcategory dropdown still says `Select Subcategory` but under that be loaded result of chosen category. In simple words:

> Instead of showing results directly, shows placeholder option and
>   results be under it.

here is my codes:

```
// HTML
<label for="specification_id">specifications</label>
  <select name="specification_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Specification</option>
  </select>

// JAVASCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').append(
                  "<option class='form-control' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>"
                  );
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you're calling `empty()` on the `select`, which, well, empties the `select`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I call `empty()` only in matter to reset results if user search for another category, if not it will show result of first and second chosen category.

Comment: Well when you empty it you remove the option..... so add in the default option....

Comment: @epascarello not sure if i get your point.

Comment: Add the option to the top of the list.... You remove everything so either copy the first item or remove the options after the first....

Comment: @epascarello i tried to replace`.append(
                  "<option class='form-control' value=''>"Select"</option>"
                  );` with `.empty()` also i tried to add this option in my existence append non of them works. would you mind share an answer to show me where i have to add that option?

Comment: `var opt = $('select[name="specification_id"] option").eq(0).clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emptying out the  item make sure to append the blank placeholder back in it:

```
else{
    $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select Specification</option>");
  }
```

or just skip it when clearing the select in the first place:

```
else{
    $('select[name="specification_id"]').not(':first').remove();
  }
```

i forgot the `empty()` in the `success:` function:

```
success:function(data) {
$('select[name="specification_id"]').not(':first').remove();
//...
```

or:

```
success:function(data) {
$('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select Specification</option>");
//...
```

Comment: @mafortis you are right since i forgot to handle the success funtion empty() statement. check out the edit. i added that.

Comment: It still does show results instead of shows our option first :\

Comment: @mafortis Does it show the "blank" option in the list though? or not at all? if it does maybe change maybe change the `append()` to `prepend()`?

Comment: could you try just removing the `empty()` calls completely to make sure the problem comes from there? (it will aggregate options but just for testing now)

Comment: when i remove `.empty` my html option will remain but as expected results all will mix

Comment: ok it works now :) here is how i did it, `$('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");` thanks to you for most of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here your option values are empty because you Call empty function.
So you can dynamically select option "Select specification "
Following procedure works fine for me, try this way

```
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty();
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').append("<option          
        class='form-control'   selected value=' '>Select 
         Specification </option>" );

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').append(
                  "<option class='form-control' value='"+ 
          value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>"
                  );
            });
```

Thank you